# Trying to reduce Django Q objects with operator.or_ seems to result in reduction with 'AND'

Tags: python, django, django-q

I am working on an application in Python/Django. I am trying to make a filter by reducing a list of Q objects with Python's operator.or_ function.
Unfortunately it results in a list that is combined with an `AND` rather than `operator.or_`.
The problem occurs in the following code:

```
print 'operator.or_', operator.or_
filter = reduce(operator.or_, q_objects[key])
print key, '->', filter
```

The statement

```
print 'operator.or_', operator.or_
```

results in

```
operator.or_ <built-in function or_>
```

so that seems succesful.
However,

```
filter = reduce(operator.or_, q_objects[key])
print key, '->', filter
```

results in (with added formatting)

```
some_key -> (
        AND: 
        ('some_field__icontains', u'search string 1'), 
        ('other_field__icontains', u'search string 2')
    )
```

As you can see, the result has an `AND` rather than an `OR`.
Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Regarding `q_objects[key]`, it is created as follows:

```
q_dict = {'some_field__icontains': u'search string 1', 'other_field__icontains': u'search string 2'}
q_objects[key] = [Q(**q_dict)]
```

Comment: What does `q_objects[key]` contain? Just wondering if it already has compound object with `AND`. Because when I try this with two simple Q objects, I get the result combined with `OR` as expected.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I added additional information to the bottom. There doesn't seem to be an 'AND'-like object in there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> q_objects[type] = [Q(**q_dict)]
> ```

No. You need to handle each element separately.

```
q_objects[type] = [Q(**{k: v}) for (k, v) in q_dict.iteritems()]
```