# Django taggit doesn't work exclude

Tags: django, django-taggit

I am using Django-taggit and works fine for me but the exclude has a problem.
Keyword is a string like 'key1 key2 key3'. The code is:

```
keyword = form.cleaned_data['keyword']
qlist = lambda x: [Q(name__icontains=x), Q(author__name__icontains=x),Q(tags__name__icontains=x)]
item_list = Item.objects.distinct()
for key in keyword.split():
    if ('-'==key[0]):
        print 'exclude: %s'%(key[1:])
        item_list = item_list.exclude(reduce(operator.or_,qlist(key[1:])))
     else:
        print 'include: %s'%(key)
        item_list = item_list.filter(reduce(operator.or_,qlist(key)))
```

It works fine for **filter()** and for the **exclude()** Q(name_*icontains=x), Q(author*_name_*icontains=x).
But, when I try to use **exclude()** with Q(tags*_name__icontains=x) it doesnt work.

Regards,
Cristian

Comment: Maybe the operator.or_ is at fault. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8138919/trying-to-reduce-django-q-objects-with-operator-or-seems-to-result-in-reduction) for details.

Comment: It is not the problem (I guess), because I run in a django console and execute:
`Item.objects.all().exclude(Q(tags__name__icontains=key)).distinct()`
And It does the same, show all the element without **exclude**

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really too versed in taggit intricacies, but... Looking at the code, it seems like the "name" is dynamically built in a lazy way.

So, if you're not populating the query explicitly, you're going to get empty request, so `Q(tags__name__icontains=key)` will be empty, and `exclude(...)` will just be like `filter(not null)`.

Try to force populating the tag query via a [select_related()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

I think, It is not supported. I found this link:
https://github.com/alex/django-taggit/issues/31